# Failed to load resource errors(405) when send Ajax data to php

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I have error ->

> "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405
>   (Method Not Allowed)"

when send Ajax data to PHP in larval.
(I made route)

**Ajax code**

```
function insertData()
{
      var text = document.getElementById('humanText').value;
      var user = document.getElementById('userName').innerText;
      $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "insertContentData",
        data:{text:text, user:user},
        success: function(data){
          alert(data);
        }
     });
     document.getElementById('humanText').value = "";
};
insertData();
```

and my php code **"insertContentData.php"**

```
<?php
  $data = $_POST['text'];
  $user = $_POST['user'];
  echo $data.", ".$user;
 ?>
```

why not work this?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Laravel has MVC pattern, in this pattern, every url map to an action in controller, so you should use url of an action, and get posted value.

Comment: Please show your route and related controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the http world the "METHOD" normally used is "GET" which is simply pulling data from the server. When you want to send data from the user to the server you used "POST". These are the two most commonly used methods.

The errors says that the METHOD IS NOT ALLOWED. You are AJAX code shows that you are using the POST method.

In Laravel you need to define a route that allows for the POST method. So instead of `Route::get($uri, $callback);` it would be `Route::post($uri, $callback);` Some more information can be found in [the Laravel Routing documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#basic-routing). However I think you are missing some concepts based on the primitive PHP code you posted, that code should be inside a [controller](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers).

Answer (score -1):

Try to run like this. I hope it works.

```js
function insertData(){
    var text = document.getElementById('humanText').value;
    var user = document.getElementById('userName').innerText;
    $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url: "insertContentData",
      data:{text:text, user:user},
      success: function(data){
        alert(data);
      }
    });
    document.getElementById('humanText').value = "";
};

window.onload = function(){
    insertData();
}
```

```html
<?php
  $data = $_POST['text'];
  $user = $_POST['user'];
  echo $data.", ".$user;
 ?>
```